# Filling a hidden field based on another form input in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I'm using omniauth and koala in a rails app to get a list of the friends (and uid's) of the logged in user. I want to let a user start typing the name of a friend and have autocomplete work so that when the user selects a friend, the form will put that friend's uid into a hidden field in the form. Seems like something that should be possible, if not easy.

One other complication is that I'm using haml so I'm not entirely comfortable with writing haml, javascript, and ruby in the same document.

Here is the HAML

```
=form_for @nag do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  =f.text_field :lendee_name, id: 'who', placeholder: 'Who owes you?'
  %div#friend-list
  =f.text_field :item, id: 'what', placeholder: 'What do they owe you?'
  =f.text_field :due_date, id: 'when', placeholder: 'When is it due?'
  =f.text_field :lendee_uid, id: 'lendee_uid', placeholder: 'Lendee uid?'

:javascript
  var allFriends = #{@friends};
```

and here is the Javascript

```
  $(function() {
    $("#who").autocomplete({
      source: allFriends,
      appendTo: $("#friend-list"),
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#who" ).val( ui.item.value );
        return false;
      },
      position: { of: "#friend-list", at: "left top" }
    }).keyup(function (e) { // Dismiss the typeahead dropdown when hitting enter
          if(e.which === 13) {
              $(".ui-menu-item").hide();
          }
      });;
  });
```

Comment: you should start with some code and what you've tried then get back here to report any trouble you encounter.

Comment: you need to update your question with your code :)

Comment: Of course I do! there we go

Comment: Im not sure you specified the problem you're currently having, if any. Is the above code not working? the javascript not working?

Comment: The autocomplete works for the #who field.. I want to dynamically fill the #lendee_uid field based on what is entered in #who field